# Distinct values in listagg without nested query

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to aggregate a column:

```
SELECT LISTAGG(name, ';  ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY name)
FROM tbl_a
INNER JOIN tbl_b ON tbl_a.foo = tbl_b.foo
WHERE tbl_a.id = 12345
```

This works fine but I want to remove duplicates, so I perform a nested query to filter the distinct ones.

```
SELECT LISTAGG(name, ';  ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY name)
FROM
(
    SELECT DISTINCT tbl_a.name
    FROM tbl_a
    INNER JOIN tbl_b ON tbl_a.foo = tbl_b.foo
    WHERE tbl_a.id = 12345
)
```

I then want to put this inside another query so I can filter on a variable value, rather than the constant `12345`:

```
SELECT
tbl_c.bar,
(
    SELECT LISTAGG(name, ';  ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY name)
    FROM
    (
        SELECT DISTINCT tbl_a.name
        FROM tbl_a
        INNER JOIN tbl_b ON tbl_a.foo = tbl_b.foo
        WHERE tbl_a.id = tbl_c.bar
    )
) as names
FROM tbl_c;
/* gets complicated, C is joined with other tables and stuff */
```

Because `tbl_c.bar` is nested twice, it shows as an invalid identifier. Therefore this approach is not possible.

**Is there any way to do a `listagg`, discarding duplicates but without nesting?**

I want the results aggregated into a single cell e.g. `name1;  name2;  name3`

---

I don't care about performance at all. Readability would be nice, though.

Comment: Talking about rep. Nice question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[RLOG's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44178114/1898563) inspired me to "solve" this myself. This is possibly inefficient, but that doesn't matter for my use-case.

Instead of filtering in the query 2nd nested query, I get *everything* and then filter the result in the 1st nested query.

```
SELECT tbl_c.bar,
(
    WITH all_names AS (
        SELECT DISTINCT tbl_a.name
        FROM tbl_a
        INNER JOIN tbl_b ON tbl_a.foo = tbl_b.foo
    )
    SELECT LISTAGG(name, ';  ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY name)
    FROM all_names
    WHERE tbl_a.id = tbl_c.bar
) as names
FROM tbl_c;
```

Answer (score 3):

This is one rather yucky solution:

```
SELECT tbl_c.bar,
       (SELECT LISTAGG(name, ';  ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY name)
        FROM (SELECT tbla.id, tbl_a.name
              FROM tbl_a INNER JOIN
                   tbl_b
                   ON tbl_a.foo = tbl_b.foo
              GROUP BY tbl_a.id
             ) x
        WHERE x.id = tbl_c.bar
       ) as names
FROM tbl_c;
```

Comment: Sure is. I dislike having to "flip" everything but looks like it would work, so upvoted anyway.

Answer (score 2):

This query may require a bit of tweaking, but I would use a factored sub-query.  Something like

```
WITH unagg AS (
        SELECT DISTINCT tbl_a.name AS names, 
               first_value(foo) over (partition by name order by foo)
        FROM tbl_a )
SELECT LISTAGG(names, ';  ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY names)
  FROM unagg
  JOIN tbl_b USING (foo)
 WHERE --condition
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. A little complex to read but you inspired me to come up with my own solution. :)

Answer (score 0):

I think your answer could be shortened to this.

```
  WITH all_names AS (
SELECT DISTINCT tbl_a.name
        FROM tbl_a
        INNER JOIN tbl_b ON tbl_a.foo = tbl_b.foo
        INNER JOIN tbl_c ON tbl_a.id = tbl_c.bar
  )
SELECT LISTAGG(name, ';  ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY name)
  FROM all_names;
```

Comment: I do need to output `tbl_c.bar` as well, though.

Comment: Ah ok, wrapper makes sense then.